# Read in contents from text box and string checked values with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, input, checkbox, datatables

I have tabulated data on a page, in the first column is checkboxes. When a user checks  multiple boxes the items are strung together, and outputted to a text box (using jquery), please refer to:

http://jsfiddle.net/YXCeD/1/

The table I am actually using a table similar to :

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html

and because the data is spread over multiple pages (loaded via ajax), I lose the checked box values when a user checks a box on another page,

ie. if apples is on the first page has been checked then the user goes to page 2 and checks oranges, the text box would update just to show oranges (but should actually show apples, oranges).

Basically I would like to modify the script so that it would simply read in the content from the text box, and then add the checked values strings (or remove if unchecked) please can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: have you checked through datatables API... you can update `aData`  which will keep your edits available on page change? The API is huge and will contain virtually anything you need

Comment: Thanks, I had a quick look but didn't know where to get started. I may go with this solution in the long run so thank you. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can have a global variable to maintain the values of your check boxes..I have modified your fiddle check that out..**

http://jsfiddle.net/kabichill/TxLWd/